# https://codepen.io/nordstromdesign/pen/gsvJj/ 3DCircle Flip Not working properly in firefox

Tags: css

Check this link a 3DCircle Flip is there. In chrome its working
 properly but in Firefox when flipping text not changing

Answer (score 0):

I've added `z-index: 2;` to the `.back {}` and this worked for me in FF.

Now the `.back{}` looks like this:

```
.back {
transform: rotate3d(45,45,0,180deg);
z-index: 2;
background-color: #fff;
}
```

I don't know the correct value of the z-index when it's applied to your project. But the value 2 worked here. You can try different values depending how many elements your are working with.